# Получение компонента обьекта юнити 3Д

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт Shooting, который висит на обьекте player, а есть скрипт BulletForceBooster, который должен обратиться к скрипту Shooting и изменить некоторые переменные без ручного внесения в инспекторе, но обьект player оно кое-как находит, а вот сам скрипт получить не может, выдаёт ошибку Null Reference. Код:

```
    public class BulletForceBooster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private float BoosterGiveForce;
    public Shooting force;


    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("player");
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        BoosterGiveForce = Random.Range(1, 4);
        Shooting force = player.GetComponent<Shooting>();
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            Pickup();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    void Pickup()
    {
        Debug.Log(force);
        force.bulletForce += BoosterGiveForce;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если выдаёт null reference, значит player он не находит, либо на нём нет соответствующего компонента

Comment: Как раз таки player он находит, и отображает его в инспекторе после запуска сцены. Компонент Shooting на нём тоже есть

Comment: И если вносить компонент в инспектор вручную, то всё хорошо. Но мне нужна автоматизация, ибо в самой игре я не смогу вставлять его вручную

Comment: "Как раз таки player он находит, и отображает его в инспекторе после запуска сцены. Компонент Shooting на нём тоже есть" --- это нонсенс. значит объект где-то уничтожается...например он появляется в триггере..........

Comment: Если делать отладку (не debug.log, а именно отладку), то на строчке `Shooting force = player.GetComponent<Shooting>();`  player не null?

Comment: force = null, player не null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Shooting force = player.GetComponent<Shooting>();
```

Тут ты создаешь новый объект класса Shooting с названием, таким же как и твое поле, сделай вот так и все заработает:

```
force = player.GetComponent<Shooting>();
```

А так же, у тебя Player публичное поле, перенеси игрока туда ручками через инспектор и убери поиск в Awake

Comment: Вау, спасибо. Всё работает прям как я хотел)